# Set Timer To Know How Fast The NFC Read The Tag

Tags: android, timer, nfc

I'm new to android, and get the project that I need to know how fast the the NFC Tag from the phone read the tag with timer. It's been 4 days and I still try to figure it out.

So this is how it works in my mind. TAG > Detected (timer start) > Information From Tag Show Up > Timer Stop.

Is it possible ? I know it will get around 0.1 miliseconds. I already can make the timer start when the tag detected, but it dont stop.

Here the java code :

```
public class Read extends Activity {


    NfcAdapter mAdapter;
    Tag mTag;
    PendingIntent mPI;
    IntentFilter mFilter[]; 
    String userData,yo;

    boolean writeMode;
    Context context;
    TextView tvNFCContent, Timer,Low;


    Button start, pause, reset, lap ;
    long MillisecondTime, StartTime, TimeBuff, UpdateTime = 0L ;
    Handler handler;
    int Seconds, Minutes, MilliSeconds ;
    ListView listView ;
    String[] ListElements = new String[] {  };
    List<String> ListElementsArrayList ;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter ;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.read);


        tvNFCContent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.data);
        Timer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timer);

        handler = new Handler() ;


        mAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
        mPI = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0,
                new Intent(this,getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP),0 );

        IntentFilter tagDetected = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED);

        IntentFilter filter2 = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
        mFilter = new IntentFilter[]{tagDetected,filter2};


    mAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    if (mAdapter == null) {
        // Stop here, we definitely need NFC
        Toast.makeText(this, "This device doesn't support NFC.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
    }

    readFromIntent(getIntent());

    }


     /******************************************************************************
     **********************************Read From NFC Tag***************************
     ******************************************************************************/
    private void readFromIntent(Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(action)
                || NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(action)
                || NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) 



        {
            Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
            NdefMessage[] msgs = null;
            if (rawMsgs != null) {
                msgs = new NdefMessage[rawMsgs.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < rawMsgs.length; i++) {
                    msgs[i] = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[i];


                }
            }                               
            buildTagViews(msgs);
        }



}



    private void buildTagViews(NdefMessage[] msgs) {
        if (msgs == null || msgs.length == 0) return;

        String text = "";
//        String tagId = new String(msgs[0].getRecords()[0].getType());
        byte[] payload = msgs[0].getRecords()[0].getPayload();
        String textEncoding = ((payload[0] & 128) == 0) ? "UTF-8" : "UTF-16"; // Get the Text Encoding
        int languageCodeLength = payload[0] & 0063; // Get the Language Code, e.g. "en"
        // String languageCode = new String(payload, 1, languageCodeLength, "US-ASCII");

        try {

            text = new String(payload, languageCodeLength + 1, payload.length - languageCodeLength - 1, textEncoding);
            TimeBuff += MillisecondTime;
            handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);         

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            Log.e("UnsupportedEncoding", e.toString());
        }


     tvNFCContent.setText("NFC Content: " + text);

    }  


    NdefMessage[] getNdefMessage(Intent intent)
    {
        NdefMessage[] msgs = null;

        Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
        if(rawMsgs != null)
        {
            msgs = new NdefMessage[rawMsgs.length];
            for(int i=0; i<rawMsgs.length; i++)
            {
                msgs[i] = (NdefMessage)rawMsgs[i];
            }
        }

        return msgs;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        setIntent(intent);
        readFromIntent(intent);
        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())){
            mTag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
            StartTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 0);
        }

        super.onNewIntent(intent);

        if(intent.getAction().equals(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED))
        {           
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Ndefdiscovered",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }else if(intent.getAction().equals(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED))
        {
            mTag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Smartcard detected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            NdefMessage[] messages = getNdefMessage(intent);            
            if(messages == null)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"There Is No Data",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }           
            byte[] payload = messages[0].getRecords()[0].getPayload();          
            userData = new String(payload);



        }else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Undefined smartcard",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }   

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        mAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        mAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, mPI, mFilter, null);

    }


    public Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            MillisecondTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - StartTime;

            UpdateTime = TimeBuff + MillisecondTime;

            Seconds = (int) (UpdateTime / 1000);

            Minutes = Seconds / 60;

            Seconds = Seconds % 60;

            MilliSeconds = (int) (UpdateTime % 1000);

            Timer.setText("" + Minutes + ":"
                    + String.format("%02d", Seconds) + ":"
                    + String.format("%03d", MilliSeconds));

            handler.postDelayed(this, 0);
        }

    };

}
```

And here the code to stop the timer, but I dont know where to put to stop the timer right on time :

```
TimeBuff += MillisecondTime;
handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With that method of reading you don't need to time how long your App spends actually reading the NFC tags as the time will always be exactly zero.

This is because the Android OS has fully read the data from the tag before the result is passed to your App.

There are ways to actually read the tag yourself if you really want to time reading the tag.

**Update:**
As you have not told me the Type of card you are using it is not possible to write the code to measure the time you want.

**Some Background:**

All NFC card operations at the low level will do 1 to N number of `transceive` operations, with each `transceive` operation sends a byte Array of 1 to N bytes and the returns a byte Array of 0 to N bytes.

For the raw read time you would time the time taken to run the right number of `transeive` command to read the data.

Timing of higher level operations would also include the time taken to parse the N number of byte Arrays in to a `NdefMessage` as well as the `transceive` commands

**The code:**

So as I don't know the card type the best I can do is get a time it takes to connect to the card and read the data and parse it to an `NdefMessage`

This is the timing of any operation that can cause RF activity and block further execution of the code.

The code ignores the fact the Android OS has already read the card and has passed you the card data with zero time in your app spent reading the card, it re-reads the card to get the timings. Note that if you take the card away to fast it can generate exceptions and fail to time reading the card.

I could have written the code to use `enableReaderMode` which is more reliable especial when writing to the card and has many other benefits. But instead I used `ForegroundDispatch` as the example code was using `ForegroundDispatch`, so I followed suit.

PS I would not recommend using `ForegroundDispatch`

```java
package com.test.foregrounddispatch;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.nfc.tech.Ndef;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    NfcAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        mAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        IntentFilter tagDetected = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED);
        IntentFilter ndefDetected = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
        try {
            ndefDetected.addDataType("*/*");
        } catch (IntentFilter.MalformedMimeTypeException e) {}
        IntentFilter techDetected = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED);
        IntentFilter[] nfcIntentFilter = new IntentFilter[]{ndefDetected,techDetected,tagDetected};

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                this, 0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
        if(mAdapter!= null)
            mAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, nfcIntentFilter, null);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);

        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            // While with ForegroundDispatch the NDEF message has already been read
            // And passed to us in the intent and thus the time the App spends "read" the NFC card is Zero
            // We want to time time the read, so now we have been notified that a NDEF card is in range
            // Try and read from it

            // Get the Tag from the intent
            Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);

            long startTime = 0;
            long endTime = 0;

            try {
                // Create an NDEF tag object
                Ndef ndefTag = Ndef.get(tag);

                // This is the I/O operation to read the card and format the result to an NDEF message
                // Nothing is done with the result to not add any time to it, as we are timing this
                startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                ndefTag.connect();
                ndefTag.getNdefMessage();
                endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                ndefTag.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("NFC", e.toString());
            }
            Log.v("NFC", "Time to read in milliseconds is: " + (endTime - startTime));
        }

    }
}
```

For a short "Hello" plain text NDEF record on my phone it produces the log:-

> V/NFC: Time to read in milliseconds is: 18

Comment: How ? I really need the answer. It's been 4 days and I really exhausted to figure this out,

Comment: The question is what exactly are you trying to measure? The time from when first read of the happens to when your app notified there is a cards? (impossible but can get a rough estimate) and or the time it takes to read the raw data from the card? and or the time it takes to parse the data to NDEF format? and or the time it takes your app to process the NDEF data? The exact type of card can influence how you would do some of these measurements and doing the measuring would also influence the results

Comment: this one "the time it takes to read the raw data from the card" not exatcly raw, I already write the NFC tag with TEXT data in it. I'm sorry if my english little bit confusing, I'm from Indonesia. I try to catch the the TEXT data that show at TEXTVIEW but it fails. Please, help me with the coding. I really need it. It almost 5 five day, and I'm not sleep yet.

Comment: it's not running, what's wrong ? this is the new java file or I need to continue my own java code and put your java code too ? 

Here is my full project [Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pn_agkgbS8CrnwNz2gXy5KR99avh1Neo)


And how to convert it to 00:00:0.18 ? can it use three number after . (dot) ? example = 00:00:0.185 ?

Comment: This is a Java file for a complete App, as your example had some incorrect logic for reading NFC it was easier to start from an Android Studio Empty App template. Milliseconds are 1/1000 of a second, so divide the number by 1000

Comment: I still use eclipse to develop android app. Could you please help me to make the code to convert the time to number in format 00:00:0.xxx ? I'm not really good at coding, I know it. I really appreciate everything you do to help me.

Comment: beside, sometimes I got 1000ms. That why I really need it in this format 00:00:0.xxx

Comment: Andrew, thanks for you help, but I still combine your code with my code. You are very kind person.  I'm really happy that you want to help me. I already ask this question but it seem no one want to answer the question. 
Thanks, at that time I'm really desperate, my fiancee go away with another man, i lost my job as a teacher, and this master degree is my last chance to help me to fixing my life. Once again, I want to say thank you Andrew, God bless you and your family.

For everyone who need the project download it [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=15-UGyCAqYeB54aF2w94csCISWj6aXZYa)