# Set Timer To Stop When Reading NFC Tag Information

Tags: java, android, nfc

I'm new to android, and get the project that I need to know how fast the time it takes to read the raw data from the card from the phone read the tag with timer. It's been 4 days and I still try to figure it out.

So this is how it works in my mind. TAG > Detected (timer start) > Information From Tag Show Up > Timer Stop. I know it will get around 0.1 miliseconds. I already could make the timer start automatically when the tag detected, but it dont stop (I hope it stop automatically when information from tag show up).

I even tried to used "Androi Textwatcher" to detect when the system send the information from Tag to TextView but it dont works either.

Here is the full project [Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pn_agkgbS8CrnwNz2gXy5KR99avh1Neo)

to stop the timer you can used this

```
TimeBuff += MillisecondTime;
handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
```

I try to put that code in any possible place in the code to stop the timer, but it dont work, please help me.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/59807214/2373819

Comment: Please help me. I really need help. Dude please.

Comment: I answer the other question this seem a duplicate of.